# I would like to ask how to add an abline legend to ggplot in this case in the R scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have mapped the Sex variable into the scatterplot, and GGPlot automatically gives me a legend for Sex, but I can't add the abline to the legend no matter what I try. I need to mark the black line as abline in the legend.

library(tidyverse)

ggplot(y_ela_test.total_sex, aes(x=Age, y=s0, color=Sex, shape=Sex)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method=lm,aes(color = Sex, fill = Sex))+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust=4, size = 10))+geom_abline(color="black",linetype="dashed",size=1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpsIp.png)
I output like this.

But I need to mark the black line as abline in the legend.

the dataset like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpsIp.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: ggplot(y_ela_test.total_sex, aes(x=Age, y=s0, color=Sex, shape=Sex)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm,aes(color = Sex, fill = Sex))+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust=4, size = 10))+geom_abline(color="black",linetype="dashed",size=1)